# Angular 2 Forms - formControl.touched true when clicking the the text area, not when leaving

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I've got a form that looks like the following:

```
       <form *ngIf="showForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
              <textarea  type="text"
                        placeholder="Description"
                        [formControl]="myForm.controls['message']">
              </textarea>
              <div class="msgError" *ngIf="myForm.controls['message'].touched">
               // Check for error in input and display error messages if invalid
              </div>

             <input type="text"
                       placeholder="Your mail"
                       [formControl]="myForm.controls['email']"/>
              <div class="emailError" *ngIf="myForm.controls['email'].touched">
              // Check for error in input and display error messages if invalid
              </div>
     </form>
```

My formGroup looks like this:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
      'message' : ['',Validators.minLength(10)],
      'email' : ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,this.emailValidator])],
    });
  }
```

My problem is that the first time I click **any** of the text fields in my form the myForm.controls.touched property becomes true instantly when the input area is selected, not when i leave the input area like it is supposed to. The consequence of this is that my error messages are displayed instantly and not when the user navigates the another field in the form. It's only the first input selected that this happens too, after the first one the other works as expected. I have no idea why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: This turned out to be a bug related to a chrome extension called virtual keyboard that I had installed in my browser e.i. not a problem related to angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This turned out to be a bug related to a Chrome extension called virtual keyboard that I had installed in my browser i.e. not a problem related to Angular 2.